# Отследить дублированное посещение сайта одним и тем же юзером

Tags: php, сессия

Добрый вечер (`currently`) всем гуру данного сайта. Такое дело (раньше не замечал и не сталкивался). Тестировал сайт и открыл его же еще в одной вкладке. Во дела! Произошло раздвоение личности у сессионных переменных (`$_SESSION['login']`). Как запретить дублированный вход на сайт? В голове вариант - создать в таблице поле "статус" и прописывать туда  "онлайн"/"не онлайн". Не знаю, правильно или нет. Это касается и входа с другого браузера с тем же, допустим, логином. Хотя при этом создается новая сессия, но все же...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Здравствуйте.*

Я решал данную проблему таким образом:

1. Создал строку в таблице пользователей `online` *1-Онлайн* | *0-Оффлайн*

При авторизации проверял если `online==1` То пропускаем скрипт, а если нет, то нет.

Но при этом, проверял последнюю активность пользователя, если она больше ежели *5минут* изменял `online` на *0*.

Вот и все :)

Comment: @IamS, 1) 5 мин ИМХО маловато, наверное.  
2) Если зайти дважды на сайт с одного и того же браузера, то авторизация не запросится, сессия-то одна - и активна. Нужно проверить, сработает ли  проверка на online в этом случае

Comment: @Deus, Можно в скрипт добавить: 

`<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){
  echo "Уже проходили авторизацию";
}
else{
  //Авторизация
}
?>`